# How to get the particular data from a database and project the value in the dropdown menu in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, mean

Html

```
<select id="releasetype" 
        name="releasetype" 
        ng-model ="changelog.releaseType" 
        class="form-control" 
        ng-options="releaseType.category as releaseType.category for releaseType in releaseTypes">
```

Controller

```
$scope.releaseTypes = changelogFactory.getCategories;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

in controller

```
$scope.releaseTypes = [];
changelogFactory.getCategories(function(data){
    $scope.releaseTypes = data;
});
```

in factory

```
return getCategories(callback){
   $http.get()
      .success(data){ 
         callback(data)
      }
}
```